# wkhtmltopdf 12.4 - QXcbConnection Could not connect to display

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, snappy

I'm getting an error (see below) and have looked through the many answers here but still have no idea how to get this to work:

**ERROR**
"The exit status code '134' says something went wrong: stderr: "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display Aborted (core dumped) " stdout: "" command: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy595ac8ce820719.82188465.html' 'TEST_874041855595ac8ce809a93.09267749.pdf'"

**SERVER**
I'm using a DigitalOcean Ubuntu 16.04 droplet with PHP 7.1 and Laravel 5.4 with Snappy and wkhtmltopdf version 12.4 64bit (everything works fine on my local Windows machine BTW), but I get the above error on the server. Here's my code:

**CODE**
$rendered_output = new Pdf('/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');
$rendered_output->generateFromHtml(view('pdf')),'file.pdf');

**INSTALLATION**
I installed wkhtmltopdf and updated the server using these commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf

**HELP**
Has anyone got any ideas how I can fix this please (even if it means using a different DO server and some other distro)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by doing two things:

1. I installed xvfb on the server: sudo apt-get install xvfb
2. I called xvfb: $snappy = new Pdf('/usr/bin/xvfb-run /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf');